# How can I strip the percent char of a number read by csvsimple?

Tags: expl3, catcodes, csvsimple, token-lists

I have a CSV table containing some numbers in percent with the percent char explictily written in the CSV data (that can’t be changes). Is there a (LaTeX3) way to strip the percent char and preceding space to only print the number (and use ist in `\num`)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
a;b;5 %
c;d;87,58 %
e;f;100,0 %
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\csvreader[no head, respect percent, separator=semicolon]{\jobname.csv}{}{%
   percent of \csvcoli (\csvcoliii)\\
}
\end{document}
```

I already got half the way and got rid of the percent char, however I’m unable to remove the space as well …

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
a;b;5 %
c;d;87,58 %
e;f;100,0 %
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xparse,csvsimple}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin:
\catcode`\%=12
   \cs_new:Nn \scores_strip_percent_and_use:n {
      \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
      \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
      \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { % } { }
      \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
\group_end:
\NewDocumentCommand { \printCSV } { } {
   \csvreader[no~head, respect~percent, separator=semicolon]{\jobname.csv}{}{
      percent~of~\csvcoli
      \c_space_tl
      (\scores_strip_percent_and_use:n { \csvcoliii }) \\
   }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\noindent\printCSV
\end{document}
```

Comment: can't you set the catcode of % to 9 (ignore)?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Hi, this is possible I guess, but would help for the space problem, would it (see also my comment toe gras answer).

Comment: Normally I wouldn't expect spaces to matter if used in a \num. E.g. `\num{123.4}x \num{123.4 }x \num{123.4~}x` works as expected.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, then this should work too :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `\regex_replace_once:nnN` it's easy: `\s*\%\Z` means “a sequence of spaces followed by `%` at the end of the token list.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
a;b;5 %
c;d;87,58 %
e;f;100,0 %
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xparse,csvsimple}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\striptrailingpercent}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \s* \% \Z } {} \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand {\printCSV}{}{%
   \csvreader[no head, respect percent, separator=semicolon]{\jobname.csv}{}{%
     \noindent percent of \csvcoli\ (\striptrailingpercent{\csvcoliii}) \par
   }
}

\begin{document}

\printCSV

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can feed the output to `\num`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
a;b;5 %
c;d;87,58 %
e;f;100,0 %
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xparse,csvsimple,siunitx}

\sisetup{group-separator=.} % just to show that \num has effect

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\striptrailingpercent}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \s* \% \Z } {} \l_tmpa_tl
  \num{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand {\printCSV}{}{%
   \csvreader[no head, respect percent, separator=semicolon]{\jobname.csv}{}{%
     \noindent percent of \csvcoli\ (\striptrailingpercent{\csvcoliii}) \par
   }
}

\begin{document}

\printCSV

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works. And I just found out that my original data contained a no-break space which therefor wasn’t found in my tests …